# Apache.Ignite.NET - Define node that caches specific affinity

Tags: .net, ignite

In Ignite.NET it is possible to cache key-value-pairs with the same affinity at 'the same' node. Is it possible to define the specific node that should be used?

Here is a test program where I'd like to define one node to cache affinity "customer" and another node to cache affinity "member".

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var ignite = Ignition.Start())

        {
            var cache = ignite.GetOrCreateCache<AffinityKey, Person>(new CacheConfiguration("person-cache")
            {
                CacheMode = CacheMode.Partitioned,
            });

            cache.Put(new AffinityKey(1, "customer"), new Person { Name = "Test customer", Age = 7 });
            cache.Put(new AffinityKey(1, "member"), new Person { Name = "Test member", Age = 7 });

            foreach (var item in cache)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}: {item.Value.Name} - {item.Value.Age}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code all customers will get in the one partition and all members will gather in the one partition too, but there's no 100% warranty that it will be two different partitions, also this means that you will have bad data distribution, because only two partition is engaged and in best case you can utilize only 2 hosts and 2 CPU cores only.

So for your case, I would advise using two different caches with node filter:
https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/configuration/CacheConfiguration.html#setNodeFilter(org.apache.ignite.lang.IgnitePredicate)

In predicate, you can specify which node should be used to store data for each cache and by this split records by nodes.

Comment: NodeFilter might work, however I do not find the equivalent in the .NET API

Comment: yep, it is not implemented for .NET API. Please see a Jira ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2890

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are in a context of CPU Affinity that is used to assign/tie a specific process/thread to some specific CPU core.

[Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/) uses Affinity for a different purpose. It is a way of [collocating](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/affinity-collocation) your entries of several data types (Caches) at the same cluster node. Thus, affinity can improve performance for cross-cache operations by addressing specific data partitions at the same node of the cluster with keeping general data distribution across the cluster.

You should use [cluster groups](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/cluster-groups) and/or node filters as Michael suggested for your purposes.

Comment: NodeFilter might work, however I do not find the equivalent in the .NET API